# using nanoseconds with boost:posix_time

Tags: c++, boost, time, compilation, posix

I need nanoseconds resolution, and I read in the Documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo

that I  have to build boost again with
`BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` defined, but I have no Idea where I should do that, or how the syntax should be. It should be in a jam file I guess. I have `boost-build.jam`, `boostcpp.jam`, `project-config.jam`. But no Idea what I should write in one of those file to make it happen.

Comment: *"To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG must be defined in the library users project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc)."* Does not sound like you need to rebuild boost, but rather define the macro during compilation of your project. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked (emphasize mine):

> To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG must be defined in the library *users* project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc).

That means, it suffices if the aforementioned macro is defined during compilation of your project. You need not rebuild boost itself.